# Java Warehouse Inventory Program: turn() method is altering properties incorrectly

Tags: java

My program is a warehouse inventory system for a Sprocket manufacturing company. Sprockets have the property of orientation (0-359 degrees, an int). There are 2 types of Sprockets: Pockets (turns clockwise) and Nockets (turns counter-clockwise), and there are 3 variations: Red (turns 5 degrees), Wooden (turns 10 degrees), and Titanium (turns 20 degrees). I have classes for Sprocket, Nocket, Pocket, RedNocket, RedPocket, WoodenNocket, WoodenPocket, TitaniumNocket, and TitaniumPocket.

I have a VirtualWarehouse object that contains a resizeable array of Sprocket objects. I can add Sprockets to the warehouse via keyboard input, where the user gives the type, variation, and quantity of Sprockets they wish to add. I need a method that turns all of the Sprocket objects the appropriate number of degrees based on what type of Sprocket they are (ex: a WoodenPocket would turn 10 degrees clockwise). My problem is that whenever I "add" a given number of Sprockets, and then tell the program to turn all of the Sprockets, the program turns every Sprocket every time it goes through the loop. For example, if I added three WoodenPockets, all of the WoodenPocket object's orientation would be advanced 10 (as it should be) three times (because three items were added). I don't understand why this is happening, so I am at a complete loss to trying to fix it. The significant portions of my code are below.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ...
        switch(userInput.toUpperCase()){
            ...
           case "ADD":
                Sprocket newSprocket = getSprocketTypeToAdd();
                System.out.print("How many of this type of sprocket would you like to
                                    add: ");
                if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                    numOfSprockets = input.nextInt();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error. You must enter an integer.");
                }
                myWarehouse.add(newSprocket, numOfSprockets);
                doMore = checkMoreInput();
                validInput = true;
                break;
            case "TURN":
                if (myWarehouse.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.print("Error: warehouse is empty. ");
                } else {
                   myWarehouse.turnAll();
                }
                doMore = checkMoreInput();//checks if user wants to continue
                validInput = true;//ends loop that catches invalid input
                break; 
            ...
        }//end switch 
        ... 
    }//end main method 
}//end Main class 


public class VirtualWarehouse {
    ...
    //properties
    private Sprocket[] warehouseContents;
    private int numberOfEntries;
    ...
    //(constructors, getters/setters, other methods)
    ... 
    public boolean add(Sprocket newEntry, int quantity) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            ensureCapacity(); //resizes array as necessary
            warehouseContents[numberOfEntries] = newEntry;
            numberOfEntries++;
            counter++;
        }
        return (counter == quantity);
    }//end add method
    ...
    public void turnAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
            warehouseContents[i].turn();
        }
    }//end turnAll method
    ...
}//end VirtualWarehouse class 


public class WoodenPocket extends Pocket {
    ...
    @Override // overrides empty methods in Sprocket and Pocket
    public void turn() {
        if (getOrientation() > 359) {//modulate orientation so it remains between 0-359
            setOrientation(getOrientation() - 360 + 10);
        } else {
            setOrientation(getOrientation() + 10);
        }
    }//end turn method 
    ...
}//end WoodenPocket class
```

If I ran the turn() method with 4 WoodenPockets with a starting orientation of 0 in the warehouse, the result would be every WoodenPocket object having an orientation of 40. I am guessing that there is a problem with the way the properties are related to the calling methods, but I don't understand what.

I have never run into something like this before (granted this is only my second semester), and I have unsuccessfully tried a variety of ways to trick the code into working (making the object a parameter of turn, making turn return the number of degrees it needs to turn, etc.). I have also examined the code with a debugger and I am just more lost.

BTW this is a homework assignment. I am really just trying to understand why the code is doing what it is doing.

Thank you!

EDIT: 
I changed the 349 to 359.
Here is a copy/paste of some input/output of my program. The numbers in curly brackets are the current Sprockets' orientations.

```
Enter would you like to do (ADD, REMOVE, TURN, RESET, REPORT, SAVE, or LOAD): add 
Enter what type of Sprocket you would like to add (POCKET or NOCKET): pocket  
Enter what variation of POCKET you would like to add (RED, WOODEN, or TITANIUM): wooden 
What are these sprockets' current orientation (between 0-359 degrees): 0
How many of this type of sprocket would you like to add: 5

Would you like to do more (YES or NO): yes
Enter would you like to do (ADD, REMOVE, TURN, RESET, REPORT, SAVE, or LOAD): report

This warehouse contains sprockets with an orientation between: 
0-59: 5  { 0 0 0 0 0 }
60-119: 0  { }
120-179: 0  { }
180-239: 0  { }
240-299: 0  { }
300-359: 0  { }

Would you like to do more (YES or NO): yes
Enter would you like to do (ADD, REMOVE, TURN, RESET, REPORT, SAVE, or LOAD): turn

Would you like to do more (YES or NO): yes
Enter would you like to do (ADD, REMOVE, TURN, RESET, REPORT, SAVE, or LOAD): report

This warehouse contains sprockets with an orientation between:
0-59: 5  { 50 50 50 50 50 }
60-119: 0  { }
120-179: 0  { }
180-239: 0  { }
240-299: 0  { }
300-359: 0  { }
```

Comment: did you make the orientation value static?

Comment: No, orientation is a non-static variable in the class Sprocket.

Comment: then maybe you only have several copies of the same object instead of several different objects

Comment: That was the problem! I have inserted both the "add" case from my main method and the add() method from my VirtualWarehouse. As you can see, I created the Sprocket object and then sent it to add(), which then adds the same object every time through the loop. In my revised code, I create the new Sprocket object inside the for loop. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

first, I believe that your turn method should be checking for 359 not 349 although I could be misinterpreting your code.

Your turn methods look fine so have you considered that you might be calling your main class every time that you add a sprocket or something similar? I think that the most likely culprit is that you are calling the turnAll method more than once.

One question I have. Have you added sprockets to the array, and then checked all of their orientations, and then called the turnAll method on the array without ever using your main class? If not please do and tell me the result.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Yes, the 349 was an error that I introduced, thanks. I can't find anywhere that I am calling turnAll() multiple times or anything similiar. I have edited the original post by adding more of my main method, and giving a sample input/output.

Comment: Try this. Add a print statement to the turnAll method, outside of the for loop. something like System.out.println("test");. Then see how many times it prints it, so you can check if that method is being called more than once.

Comment: The problem is fixed now. As you can see in the comments under the original post, the problem was in my add function. Thank you so much for your help!